# Light DOM style cascades down to the shadow DOM

Tags: css, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I have created a custom element with polymer. When the element is included within an `h2`, it inherits the `h2`'s `boldness` and `font-size`. I need my components to be sheltered from the outside world and not be affected by light dom styles. How can I achieve this if the light DOM cascades down?

To be more specific, check out the following:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be [by design](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-scoping/#inheritance):

> The top-level elements of a shadow tree inherit from their host element.

The host element in this case is the `h2`.

You will need to include explicit size and weight declarations in your custom element's CSS in order to prevent it from inheriting the styles from its host element.

Comment: I see the problem here but, it is a bit confusing and let me explain why: Within my custom element, the ``:host`` in a stylesheet refers to ``x-component`` and not to the ``h2``. When I style my ``:host`` then these styles apply to ``x-component``. Yet event another problem is that I have a chrome extension that dynamically modifies the DOM and I need the styling to stay consistent. I am thinking about including a reset script within my components. What are your thoughts? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset your CSS to the browsers defaults using `all: initial;` in the `:host`

```
:host {
    all: initial;
}
```

Not supported in IE or Edge but neither is shadow DOM.

Another option is to use a CSS reset in your web component such as [normalize.css](https://github.com/csstools/normalize.css)

Apparently there are browser optimisations in place to handle identical CSS in multiple web components so it's not as inefficient as it sounds.